# No live preview available when entry status is set to disabled?

Tags: live-preview, status

I have a few entries which are set to disabled. It seems that the live preview is not working then. It only works when the entry status is enabled.

This seems more like a bug than a feature, right?

---

**Update**

I have checked everything again and all conditions stated by Brandon below are met, but now I see that I actually don't use the "entries own url" setting. It's enabled, so I get the live preview button, but I use dynamic routing to create my own url's (because I need to add a category as a segment in the URL).

So that's probably where it goes wrong. I check the last segment of the URI as the slug of the specific entry and set my entry manually by it.

So how do I make live preview work than?

Comment: Include your partial into the template specified in the section's settings. Or redirect.

Answer (score 7):

Live Preview will be available when the following are true:

- The section’s “Entries in this section have their own URLs” setting is checked
- The section’s “Entry Template” setting points to a valid template path
- The entry has been saved

It doesn’t matter if the entry is enabled or not.

Comment: All of those conditions are met. I'll send in some logs from the dashboard widget.

Comment: I have checked everything again and all conditions are met, but now I see that I actually don't use the "entries own url" setting. It's enabled, so I get the live preview button, but I use dynamic routing to create my own url's (because I need to add a category as a segment in the URL). So that's probably where it goes wrong. I check the last segment of the URI as the slug of the product and set my entry manually by it. So how do I make live preview work than?

Comment: @TomDeSmet You should probably create a new thread for that last question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your entry has a category field in it? In your section's settings, use something like this for the format URL:

```
{myCategoryField.first().slug}/{slug}
```

No need to roll you own routing, Craft will add the category's slug to your URL and do all of that properly for you.